# Are Goodberries affected by the Life domain class features?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, healing

How are Goodberries affected by the cleric class features from the Life domain, if at all? I read somewhere that the Life domain's healing bonuses apply to each berry created by the spell — do they? Are there any official answers to this question?

Comment: +1 beautiful question... the answer of which has saved our party many many times. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, a Life Domain cleric's Goodberrys are great.

> The Disciple of Life feature would make each berry restore
> 4 hit points, instead of 1, assuming you cast *goodberry* with a 1st-level slot. ([Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf) for fifth edition.)

---

For any who aren't aware, "Sage Advice" is the long-standing name given to TSR's, then WotC's, [official](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84836/23970) clarifications to rules. Each month questions worth clarifying are answered by Jeremy Crawford, "rules manager" for 5e, and are concatenated into a Sage Advice compendium.

There is a commonly-referenced website called "Sage Advice" which should not be confused with the articles--this site compiles tweets about D&D rules from various sources, and is not authoritative. But it is informative, as some of those tweets come from the designers of D&D5e, including Jeremy Crawford.

Comment: Hehe... "Greatberry"

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

[Disciple of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DiscipleofLife-131) activates when a spell of first level or higher is "used" to restore hit points:

> Whenever you **use a spell** of 1st level or higher to **restore hit points** to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

[Goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry) is level 1, and it certainly is used to restore hit points:

> Eating a berry **restores 1 hit point**

This also applies to other spells which are used to restore hit points directly, as well as indirectly; such as Healing Spirit, Aura of Life, or even Wish.

Comment: Why the downvote? Even if this answer doesn't address the OP asking for an official answer for this situation, it still answers pretty well the first question. Please remember to leave a comment when you downvote an answer to help improve it.