# How much health will a Life Domain cleric regain from the Blessed Healer feature using the Mass Healing Word spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, healing

This question could loosely be considered a follow up to "[Can Goodberries heal a Life cleric when consumed by another](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84800/25601)."

How much life would a level 6 Life Cleric with four party members gain from the Blessed Healer class attribute with a casting of Mass Healing Word?

**Blessed Healer**

> Beginning at 6th level, the healing spells you cast on others heal you
>   as well. When you cast a spell of 1st level or higher that restores
>   hit points to a creature other than you, you regain hit points equal
>   to 2 + the spell’s level.

**Mass Healing Word**

> As you call out words of restoration, up to six creatures of your
>   choice that you can see within range regain hit points equal to 1d4 +
>   your spellcasting ability modifier. This spell has no effect on undead
>   or constructs.

If the Cleric casts Mass Healing Word, targeting each of the 4 party members, how many times would the Cleric gain HP equal to 2 + Spell Level?

Taken further, would the Blessed Healer effect be prevented if the Cleric targeted himself with Mass Healing Word, in addition to the other 4 members of his party?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> If the Cleric casts Mass Healing Word, targeting each of the 4 party members, how many times would the Cleric gain HP equal to 2 + Spell Level?

I would argue only once, because the trigger for Blessed Healer is "When you cast a spell...". You only cast one spell, so you'd only get healed once.

> Taken further, would the Blessed Healer effect be prevented if the Cleric targeted himself with Mass Healing Word, in addition to the other 4 members of his party?

That's easier to answer. I'd say no, the effect is not prevented, since casting *mass healing word* to heal at least one person other than yourself clearly satisfies the requirement for Blessed Healer.

Comment: One spell, multi-target. Totally agree.

Answer (score 4):

**Blessed Healer would trigger once** whether you target yourself or not, unless you were the only target of the *mass heal*.

Another way to read the ability would be "When you cast a spell... that restores hit points to ***at least one*** creature ***other than you***..."

Even if you choose yourself as one of the targets, unless there were no other targets of the spell, *Blessed Healer* would still trigger, because you are still affecting creatures other than yourself.