# Do the Life cleric's Disciple of Life and Blessed Healer features stack when using a spell that heals both the cleric and another creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, healing, stacking

A 6th-level [Life Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain) has the following gets the [Disciple of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DiscipleofLife-131) feature at 1st level:

> Also starting at 1st level, your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

And the [Blessed Healer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#BlessedHealer-133) feature at 6th level:

> Beginning at 6th level, the healing spells you cast on others heal you as well. When you cast a spell of 1st level or higher that restores hit points to a creature other than you, you regain hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

Suppose I, a life cleric with a Wisdom modifier of +3, cast [Mass Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-healing-word) at 3rd level, which heals 1d4+3 hit points to multiple creatures. If I include both myself and another creature as targets of the spell, how many hit points would I heal? Would I gain the benefits from both Disciple of Life and Blessed Healer?

Comment: Related: [What is the interaction between the Aura of Vitality spell and the Life Domain cleric's Blessed Healer feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163584/what-is-the-interaction-between-the-aura-of-vitality-spell-and-the-life-domain-c) (it mentions the spell's interaction with both features), [How much health will a Life Domain cleric regain from the Blessed Healer feature when casting the Mass Healing Word spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84821/how-much-health-will-a-life-domain-cleric-regain-from-the-blessed-healer-feature)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, the benefits would stack.

You would gain benefits from both effects.

Disciple of Life gives bonus HP to the creature you heal, which can include yourself as you are a creature, the same as any of your party members.

Blessed Healer gives the Cleric HP if a creature other than the Cleric is healed, which in the example given is indeed the case.

Therefore, your *mass healing word* spell would cause creatures other than you to regain 1d4 + 3 + 5 HP, and cause you to regain 1d4 + 3 + 10 HP.

Comment: This makes me wish I wasn't planning to multiclass into Druid with my Cleric, I could use the extra benefit of Blessed Healer to help me when I'm taking extra damage through _warding bond_.  I'll still get it eventually but dang I want it now.