# Which healing spells benefit from the Circle of Stars druid's "Chalice" Starry Form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, druid, healing

The [Circle of Stars druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleofStars)'s [Starry Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#StarryForm-2996434) feature (TCoE, p. 38-39) lets the druid expend a use of Wild Shape to enter a starry form, choosing a constellation to glimmer on their body that grants certain benefits. The Chalice option grants the following benefit:

> A constellation of a life-giving goblet appears on you. Whenever you
> cast a spell using a spell slot that restores hit points to a
> creature, you or another creature within 30 feet of you can regain hit
> points equal to 1d8 + your Wisdom modifier.

**Which healing spells benefit from/interact with the "Chalice" Starry Form?**

It's obvious how some healing spells (e.g. *cure wounds* or *healing word*) interact with it, and so I don't think I need clarification on them - but some others are less obvious to me.

For instance, the [*goodberry*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry) spell creates berries that can be eaten within the next 24 hours to restore 1 HP to the creature:

> Up to ten berries appear in your hand and are infused with magic for the duration. A creature can use its action to eat one berry. Eating a berry restores 1 hit point, and the berry provides enough nourishment to sustain a creature for one day.

Meanwhile, the [*healing spirit*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-spirit) spell creates an intangible spirit that you can cause to heal a creature in the same space (XGtE, p. 157):

> You call forth a nature spirit to soothe the wounded. The intangible
> spirit appears in a space that is a 5-foot cube you can see within
> range. The spirit looks like a transparent beast or fey (your choice).
>
> Until the spell ends, whenever you or a creature you can see moves
> into the spirit’s space for the first time on a turn or starts its
> turn there, you can cause the spirit to restore 1d6 hit points to that
> creature (no action required). The spirit can’t heal constructs or
> undead. The spirit can heal a number of times equal to 1 + your
> spellcasting ability modifier (minimum of twice). After healing that
> number of times, the spirit disappears.

Finally, the [*aura of vitality*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-vitality) spell creates an aura that moves with you and lets you use a bonus action to heal an ally in the aura (PHB, p. 216):

> Healing energy radiates from you in an aura with a 30-foot radius.
> Until the spell ends, the aura moves with you, centered on you. You
> can use a bonus action to cause one creature in the aura (including
> you) to regain 2d6 hit points.

(*Aura of vitality* isn't normally on the druid spell list, but it's added to the druid spell list by the ["Additional Druid Spells"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/druid#AdditionalDruidSpells) optional class feature (TCoE, p. 35).)

None of these 3 spells immediately heals a character at the moment it's cast, but each one creates an effect that can then heal a creature. Do these qualify for the benefit of the Chalice form?

Comment: Related: "[What is the interaction between the Aura of Vitality spell and the Life Domain cleric's Blessed Healer feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163584)" and "[Can Goodberries heal a Life cleric when consumed by another?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84800)"

Answer (score 8):

Chalice states:

> A constellation of a life-giving goblet appears on you. Whenever you
> cast a spell using a spell slot that restores hit points to a
> creature, you or another creature within 30 feet of you can regain hit
> points equal to 1d8 + your Wisdom modifier.\

"Whenever you cast a spell" is the important bit.  It does not state "whenever a healing effect you produce" or "whenever one of your spells would cause healing", it states the condition "you cast a spell".

On top of that, there's an extra qualifier to the condition.  "Whenever you cast a spell **that restores hit points**."  The effect of the spell must include restoring hitpoints.

Goodberry - Casting Goodberry creates berries, and doesn't restore hit points.  Eating a berry restores hit points, but is not casting a spell.  It does not benefit from Chalice.

Aura of Vitality - Using a bonus action to initiate your healing aura's ability is not casting a spell, and will not benefit from Chalice.

Healing Spirit - Moving into a space in the healing spirit's AoE is not casting a spell, and will not benefit from Chalice.

Comment: But does *casting* Goodberry trigger it? (Or any of the others, really)

Comment: My answer specifies "it will not benefit".  None of the spells I list in my answers heal as part of casting the spell.

Comment: While I agree, I would like this answer to expand briefly on whether a DM adjudicating differently from the RAW would be acceptable for a table

Comment: I can't weigh in on whether it would be acceptable for a table.  That's an agreement between the players and the DM, and outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Lovell Good point.  I edited my answer to take it into consideration; please let me know what you think.