# Can a Werewolf actually hurt another Werewolf?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, immunities, lycanthropy

This came up today in Curse of Strahd. One of the werewolves wanted to aid the party in taking out some of her fellows.

It occurred to me that a Werewolf in hybrid form does piercing (bite) and slashing (claws) damage which werewolves are immune to.

Are werewolves actually immune to other werewolves assuming said werewolf does not have access to a silvered weapon?

Comment: She could put the other werewolf in a hold for you though. "You hold 'em, I'll hit 'em."

Comment: @T.E.D. - Yeah, she went the route of tripping and taking out some mundane wolves.

Comment: Related: [Are there any other ways for lycanthropes to hurt other lycanthropes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174589/are-there-any-other-ways-for-lycanthropes-to-hurt-other-lycanthropes)

Answer (score 35):

I asked Chris Perkins this question, and his response was:

> A werewolf needs magic, a magic weapon, or a silvered weapon to harm another werewolf. [[1]](https://twitter.com/ChrisPerkinsDnD/status/765005740180279296)

While he generally refers rules questions to Jeremy Crawford, this makes sense in relation to Curse of Strahd and why this particular werewolf would want the PC's assistance.

Comment: @Mindwin Nope. "The public statements of the D&D team, or anyone else at Wizards of the Coast, are not official rulings; they are advice. One exception: the game’s rules manager, Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford), can make official rulings and usually does so in Sage Advice." (From the head-matter of Sage Advice.) See also: [Where do I find the “official” rules for D&D 5e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84836/23970)

Comment: (Just to be clear, this answer's perfectly *correct*; I'm just saying that Perkins' word doesn't make it so. The text of the werewolf's stat-block makes it so.)

Answer (score 2):

**Answer A:** (not so serious)

Since you only banned silvered weapons, I present to you:

**[THE TORCH](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/torch)**

Dealing a whopping ONE (1) *fire damage* on a hit.Yay.

I know it's kind of a loophole since it simply uses a different kind of equipment than the banned-for-this-question silvered ones but hey. [If this fits your question you could also use any other magical weapon, since the immunity is exclusively to nonmagical slashing etc. damage.

**Answer B:** (fully serious)

**Push em off a cliff.** Your last sentence just states "immune to other werewolfes", while their description clearly states

> From Nonmagical **Attacks** Not Made With Silvered Weapons [Emphasis mine]

So the fall damage that Werewolf B  (indirectly) causes Werewolf A  is not an attack and therefore fully hits. Whether it's an out-of-combat strength/athletics contest or in-combat the 'special melee attack'  for shoving Werewolf B off said cliff is dependent on the DM but the result could be the same.

[The same thing apparently also counts for traps, since they do not make "attacks" either](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/what-counts-as-an-attack)

There you go, Werewolfes can indeed hurt each other, just not too directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are fully immune provided you use solely their stat blocks. To damage from attacks that is.

A werewolf would need a different way to kill another werewolf. Some include falling damage or drowning

In your situation the helpful werewolf is also immune to her enemies, thus she can be of tremendous help to the part, for example she can grapple them and they can do nothing but try to escape, since while they may attack her, they can do no damage.

Comment: We do ask that answers be fully supported by either rules or subjective experience done or seen. You can read more about our [citation expectations here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696). You're doing a great job in becoming active here, but please review your answers with the guidelines and expectations we review in the Meta linked above.