# Does the Grappler feat give advantage on a subsequent shove attempt vs. your grappled target?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, grapple, advantage-and-disadvantage

The [Grappler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/grappler) feat says it gives advantage on attack rolls against a creature you are grappling.

Does this include attempts to shove the grappled creature?

Comment: Very related on [Does a Grapple or Shove count as an attack for the Mobile feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116663/)

Answer (score 13):

## Shove does not use an attack roll

[Shoving a Creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) is described as (emphasis added):

> The target must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach. Instead of making an attack roll, you make a **Strength (Athletics) check** contested by the target's Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use).

Since Grappler specifies Attack Rolls and Shoving uses an ability check you do not get advantage on checks to shove a grappled creature.

Answer (score 5):

### No, shoves are not covered by the Grappler feat

From the Combat chapter of the PHB/basic rules, in particular the '[Shoving a Creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature)' section:

> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

This makes it sound like it would work, but the key phrase in the [Grappler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/grappler) feat is the term "attack rolls".

[Attack rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#AttackRolls) are specifically defined as follows:

> When you make an attack, your attack roll determines whether the attack hits or misses. To make an attack roll, roll a d20 and add the appropriate modifiers. If the total of the roll plus modifiers equals or exceeds the target's Armor Class (AC), the attack hits. The AC of a character is determined at character creation, whereas the AC of a monster is in its stat block.

Therefore, a shove attempt, although it is a special type of attack, does **not** constitute an attack roll, and so it is not affected by the Grappler feat.

Comment: "changed Roll20 links to point to DDB instead (due to incorrect capitalization in rules quotes from Roll20 Compendium entry)" - noted, I'll remember that for the future. Thanks, V2Blast