# Does being slowed prevent using multiple shoves/grapples during an attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, grapple, conditions, multiattack

If a creature has been slowed either from the [slow spell](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Slow#h-Slow) or a [stone golem's](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Stone%20Golem#content) slow ability, it can't make more than one attack per turn. If a character can make multiple attacks per turn however (eg. via extra attack) they can normally substitute a shove or a grapple in place of one of those attacks. Can a character capable of multiple attacks per turn, who is currently slowed, make a single weapon attack and then use their remaining attacks to shove/grapple?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey The rules state that, if you can normally make multiple weapon attacks as part of an attack action, you can substitute shove or grapple in place of one of those attacks. Even if you can't shove multiple creatures (I can't see anything preventing it) I'm asking if you can use an attack and a shove/grapple if you are slowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[Does a Grapple or Shove count as an attack for the Mobile feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116663)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Grapples and shoves are attacks; you only get one attack while affected by *slow*

The [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell states:

> [...]  Regardless of the creature's abilities or magic items, **it can't make more than one melee or ranged attack during its turn** [...]

The sections on "[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling)" and "[Shoving a Creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature)" state:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make **a special melee attack,** a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them [...]
>
> Using the Attack action, you can make **a special melee attack** to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them [...]

This shows us that both grappling and shoving are considered attacks, and thus the *slow* spell also prevents you from making multiple grapples or shoves, or even a regular attack and a grapple/shove. You only get one attack, total, for your turn, this includes regular attacks, grapples, and shoves.

Some questions on similar/related things:

- [Does a Grapple or Shove count as an attack for the Mobile feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116663)
- [Does grappling count as a hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91864)
- [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781)