# Language discrepancy between SRD and PHB

Tags: dnd-5e

In the [Systems Reference Document (SRD)](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) text of *polymorph* it is stated that

> The spell has no effect on a shapechanger or a creature with 0 hitpoints

However in my PHB copy it is worded as

> An unwilling creature must make a Wisdom saving throw to avoid the effect. A shapechanger automatically succeeds on this saving throw.

Implying that a willing shapechanger can be effected since it only allows a success on a save that is only rolled by an unwilling target. I was unable to find an errata on this subject.

What is the RAW in this case? The SRD was published later than PHB--does it make it more official? Is this even an intentional change? Is there an errata I am missing somewhere?

Comment: Related: [Where do I find the official rules for D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84836/23970)

Comment: Related: [How compatible are 5E rules with SRD rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96577/how-compatible-are-5e-rules-with-srd-rules), [Difference between the SRD and the Basic Rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/difference-between-the-srd-and-the-basic-rules)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The spell wording in your PHB is out of date

The SRD, D&D Beyond, and the revised PHB agree that your version is not the most up-to-date version.

If you look on D&D Beyond, you can currently find the most up-to-date information. [The description of *polymorph* on DDB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) tells us:

> The spell has no effect on a shapechanger or a creature with 0 hit points.

My PHB says "first printing  August 2014 (This printing includes corrections to the first printing.)” and it includes the exact same phrasing as I quoted above (the same as on the SRD and DDB).

Oddly enough, I cannot find an errata that changes the wording of the shapechanger part in the PHB. The [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) does note when  the "0 hit points" part was added however.

### SRD is not an official rules source

Note that the [SRD is not an official rules source.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/949111823990534144) It just so happens that it was updated after your  PHB was printed and thus happens to be right in this case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72617/discussion-on-answer-by-rubiksmoose-language-discrepancy-between-srd-and-phb).

Comment: This answer is being talked about on the Stack Exchange Meta here: [Is D&D Beyond an official rules source?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7742/28591)

Answer (score 11):

While the SRD does not override the PHB, the newer printing of the PHB has the same wording as the SRD, as covered [by Rubiksmoose](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114753/15469).

According to the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://dnd.wizards.com/sage-advice-compendium):

> The fifth edition of D&D has three official rulebooks, each of which was first published in 2014:
>
> - Player’s Handbook  (abbreviated  PH)
> - Monster  Manual  (abbreviated  MM)
> - Dungeon Master’s Guide  (abbreviated  DMG)

The SRD is not even mentioned here. On [its page](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), it says:

> The Systems Reference Document (SRD) contains guidelines for publishing content under the Open-Gaming License (OGL).

So no, the SRD is not an official rules source and does not override the official rulebooks. It exists as a tool for publishers, not as a free rules resource. That role is occupied by the Basic Rules.

Comment: To back this up, ["Note that the SRD is not an official rules source for D&D."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/949111823990534144).

Comment: It is worth noting that in this case OP's PHB is out of date regardless of the SRD's official status.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Is the specific sentence in my post out of date? If so yes that is relevant but otherwise I think mere existence of errata obviously makes all pre-errata material out of date so probably no specification is needed.