# Is Tales of Old an official bard ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, content-identification

It’s my second time playing D&D and I’m playing a bard this time around, so I’ve been doing some research on the class.
I don't have the Player’s Handbook yet, so I do all of my research on websites and I always double check to make sure it’s a 5e cite.

I came across something called “tales of old” on this one website, where you could recall a story and tell this story out loud to get buffs, or debuffs on enemies.

I accidentally closed the tab so I looked up “tales of old 5e” on google and on a couple D&D dictionaries and I couldn't find it.

Was it made up? Is it not called “tales of old”?

Comment: ok I found it it was on the wiki under bard the only problem is It doesn't specify in what scenario you can use these or how to

Comment: This one? https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Bard,_Variant_(5e_Class)#Tales_of_Old

Comment: no it was this one - https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Bard,_Variant_(5e_Class) - but that link was a lot more useful it fixed my problem thanks for the help I appreciate it

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Hmmm, "Tales of Old" is what it's called, then? Further adds to my suspicion that I'm a Bard, of sorts, anyway. Many thanks.

Answer (score 18):

[This variant bard class](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Bard,_Variant_(5e_Class)#Tales_of_Old) seems to have the feature you're looking for, but be advised, this is what we call a "Homebrew".

What you're looking at is *not* official material, and many GMs will straight up deny anything that comes from D&Dwiki.

Just take a moment to read this: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/)

D&D wiki is *not* the place for someone who's starting to play to look at.

Use the Basic Rules if you don't have the books. See the [PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) or look at them online on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) (Thanks to V2Blast for this)

Comment: Just a note: [the SRD isn't an official rules resource; it's a guideline describing what content can be published under the OGL](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/difference-between-the-srd-and-the-basic-rules). (Of note, the SRD hasn't been updated as of the 2018 core rules errata.) It'd be better to direct OP to the basic rules instead ([here as a PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf), or [here on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules)).

Comment: Thanks for that, I edited my answer to add your links as they are much better suited for this case.

Comment: There's an interesting question on UX from a D&D Wiki admin about why people don't realise content is homebrew. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120541/why-do-people-not-notice-our-enormous-prominent-clear-and-contrasting-purple-b

Answer (score 5):

## No, that is not in any way an official thing

So, first of all, almost anything that *is* official will be visible on D&D beyond under the Bard class or, if you prefer, in your copy of the Player's Handbook.  Everything beyond that is going to be an alternate subclass or new spell.  The non-core subclasses for bard are:

- glamour
- satire*
- swords
- whispers

none of these have the ability you mention.  The non-core spells for a bard also don't provide any ability like that.

As you note, the ability you found is on D&D wiki in a section marked 'Homebrew'.  'Homebrew' means unofficial stuff published non-comercially.  D&D wiki in particular has a bad reputation regarding the quality of their homebrew, and this bard variant is no exception-- the material presented therein is both far too voluminous and possessed of abilities which are independently much too powerful.  Even beyond being homebrew, *that* material is unlikely to be okay in a game.

* Satire is published as Unearthed Arcana which, while totally official, is playtest content rather than finished product.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Satire isn't a published bard subclass; it was only in an old [2015 UA](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/04_UA_Classics_Revisited.pdf) (i.e. playtest content).

Comment: @V2Blast I mean, it's *published*, just not republished in an official for-sale printed book.  It is, as you say, 'playtest' content, but it's still official content.  I'll make a note.