# How can I look up all spells fitting given criteria?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

What’s the best way to find spells meeting certain criteria in D&D 5e? For example, I'm currently working on a warlock and I want to see a list of all cantrips that scale with the spell slot used. Another example would be looking up all spells that do a particular type of damage (fire, cold, etc.).

Comment: Note that cantrips do not use a spell slot, and thus do not scale with slot used. They automatically scale with character level, and so the answer to your question is technically "all of them", though some have no improved effect with increased caster level. If this clarification solves your problem, then great, otherwise you might need to rephrase to "cantrips that benefit from increased character level" or "spells that scale with spell slot". Assuming, of course, you can restate this so that it is no longer a shopping question.

Comment: With only a slight edit this question clearly fits out “ask about your problem and answers about tools are OK” model on how to ask questions that might have Rec-ish answers but not be a straight shopping question.

Answer (score 11):

## DnDBeyond is what you want

The best official tool for looking up spells online currently is [DnDBeyond](http://dndbeyond.com/spells).<sup>1</sup> DnDBeyond is Wizard of the Coast's [officially-licenced online source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114911/is-dd-beyond-an-official-rules-source) for rules. It has an extensive spell search function. It will not allow you to filter specifically for scaling cantrips, but you can filter by spell level (including cantrip), damage type, class and by many other parameters.

For example, [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/class/warlock?filter-search=&filter-damage-type=50&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=) is the spell list filtered for Warlock spells that do cold damage.

Note that by default, you will only be able to access details for spells that are in the Basic Rules or from sources you own. For example, if you tried to access the details for the spell [*illusory dragon*](https://dndbeyond.com/spells/illusory-dragon) you would be prompted to purchase all or part of *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* in order to access it.

Still, you should see the names of all the spells in your search regardless of what online sources you own. So even if you can't access the details online, you can still look it up in the physical books you own.

---

<sup>1 - For comparison I have also used both Roll20 and Fantasy Grounds before. Neither of whom can beat DnDBeyond in amount of content, ease of use, and/or number of filters. Roll20 has issues in general that make it a subpar resource compared to DnDBeyond as well. Fantasy Grounds must be installed as an application in order to be used. To my knowledge, these are the only two other officially licensed sources for online-searchable spells. This is why I say that DnDBeyond is the best source for these things currently.</sup>