# Are there any other prestige classes for 5e besides the Rune Scribe?

Tags: dnd-5e, prestige-class, unearthed-arcana

In the Unearthed Arcana article "[Prestige Classes and Rune Magic](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/prestige-classes-and-rune-magic)", they introduce the idea of prestige classes, a class with only a few levels and more multiclassing prerequisites, borrowed from earlier editions (I remember them from 3.5e, but only via NWN2 rather than the real game).

In the same article, they give the Rune Scribe prestige class as an example. Excluding random homebrew, **have there been any other prestige classes for 5e?** Since prestige classes were only ever a UA thing, I imagine other UA articles are the only places they would likely have been released, but I was unable to find anything going through them myself. But there may have been some other semi-official source I am unaware of...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### As of now: No

While this might change with future releases, there are no prestige classes, nor rules for such, officially published (outside that Unearthed Arcana entry). There are not any published on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/) (they don't even list the Rune Magic entry in their UA materials) nor in any of the [official books](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e).

---

As possible sign that this is possibly never coming can be found in said UA article:

> Many    of    the    character    concepts    that    were    once    prestige    classes    or    paragon    paths    in    earlier    editions    of    D&D    are    now    options    available    to    1st‑level    characters.    In    general,    the    game’s    design    aims    for    maximum flexibility,    making    options    available    to    all    characters.

Indicating that prestige classes is not the way they wish to enable new (and old) character concepts, but rather through new subclasses, as they have been doing (see XGtE in particular).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I completely agree that prestige classes are entirely redundant in 5e since 5e has class archetypes instead, hence I very much doubt we'll be seeing anything new, but I was curious to see if they'd done anything more with this idea back then around about the time when that article came out. Thank you for confirming my suspicion that it was literally just this one article after all.