# Which of these sources for Aarakocra lifespan is correct?

Tags: dnd-5e, aging, aarakocra

I've been trying to find out how long aarakocra live for because I'm creating an Aarakocra character. However, I've found conflicting information across different sites.

[D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) and the [*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*](http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf#page=5) state:

> ***Age.*** Aarakocra reach maturity by age three. Compared to humans, aarakocra don't usually live longer than 30 years.

[This Tribality article](https://www.tribality.com/2014/10/12/aarakocra/) states:

> **Age.** An aarakocra reaches adulthood at the age of 20 years and they have been known to live as long as 200 years.

The [grpg.wikidot.com](http://grpg.wikidot.com/race:aarakocra) site says:

> Aarakocra can live to be over 100 years old.
>
> Aarakocra have the same life expectancy and age categories as humans.

Which of these is correct? How long do aarakocra actually live?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you haven't already. This is a good first question, good job including your sources and quotes. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Only one of those is an official source

The listing from [DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) is the only one that is officially supported. The others are fan sites or wiki that don't have official status. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84837/48759) has a complete (as of most recent edit) list of available official sources.

DNDBeyond is referencing the [Elemental Evil Player's Companion](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf) where the Aarakocra was officially released in 2015. Therefore the correct answer is:

> **Age.** Aarakocra reach maturity by age three. Compared to humans, aarakocra don't usually live longer than 30 years.

The [tribality link](https://www.tribality.com/2014/10/12/aarakocra/) is a homebrew race by Rich Howard created before the official version was released.

Similarly the [grpg.wikidot version](http://grpg.wikidot.com/race:aarakocra) was last edited in 2011 before the official version was released. In fact the race is actually compatible with D&D 3.5e not 5e so isn't relevant material anyway. It doesn't have an author credit but is a public wiki and can be edited.

Comment: There might be some confusion related to the D&D version, too. It's been a very long while since the days where I was playing AD&D (2nd ed), but I don't recollect them being presented as so short lived back in the 90s.

Comment: I checked the 1st ed. Fiend Folio, the 2nd ed. Monstrous Manual, and the 3rd ed. Monsters of Faerûn, and neither gives any age for them.

Answer (score 9):

The reason you've found conflicting information across different sites is because only one of those sites hosts the official (correct) stats of an Aarakocra for D&D 5e.

#### Let's start with grpg.wikidot.com.

This site hosts potentially modified D&D 3.5 content so isn't really relevant to D&D 5e.

> This is a guide to the base Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 rules set used in our campaigns. [...] There are a number of alterations to skills, feats and spells as they are applied to our campaigns. Read carefully! <sub>[source](http://grpg.wikidot.com/rules:index)</sub>

#### Next is Tribality.

This appears to be a homebrewed race created before the official release of Aarakocra as a playable race as noted by:

> Here’s a snipet with just the traits from Rich’s fully fleshed out build…

I'm not sure where they're sourcing their information from (other than the 5e Monster Manual) but again, it's not official and not really relevant.

#### And lastly, [D&D  Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra).

> D&D Beyond [is] an official digital toolset for Dungeons & Dragons fifth edition. <sup>[source](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/ddbeyond)</sup>

Therefore, D&D Beyond is the only source (of the 3) that is providing the official stats for the Aarakocra.

If you want to be 100% sure though you can freely download the officially published source book - the [Elemental Evil Player's Companion](http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf) - and check the stats of for yourself.