# What is "Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron"?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, eberron

I have seen that WotC is coming out with a Eberron campaign source book titled *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* - but I have seen references to something called *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, which I thought was the Eberron campaign guide.

What is *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*?

Comment: Related on [Where do I find the official rules for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e)

Comment: Related question by me: [What material appears in the “Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron” that wasn't reprinted in the “Eberron: Rising from the Last War” book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174844/what-material-appears-in-the-wayfinders-guide-to-eberron-that-wasnt-reprinte)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## It's a digitally published book by Wizards of the Coast

You can read the description of this playtest material on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte) and via [DMsGuild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/247882/Wayfinders-Guide-to-Eberron-5e).

It is described as:

> Eberron was born in 2002 when Wizards of the Coast launched a worldwide search for a new campaign setting.
>
> *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* brings the eponymous campaign setting to the fifth edition of Dungeons & Dragons. This 175 page book gives you everything you need to create an Eberron story or character, exploring the core themes of the setting and the rules to implement them in fifth edition. It includes an overview of Khorvaire and the fantastic city of Sharn, along with a host of background ideas and story hooks.
>
> Playtest material includes the unique races of Eberron, the mystical dragonmarks (including greater dragonmarks and aberrant dragonmarks), and new magic items; this is a living document, and this content will evolve and be updated in response to feedback.

Keith Baker also discusses it [on his site](http://keith-baker.com/wgte/).

The introduction to the book also makes clear it's a work in progress for purposes of being a living document to help guide and inspire you and not be prescriptive rules:

> Bear in mind: this book presents my current vision of Eberron. This is the world I run at my own table, and the way that I’ve converted its ideas to fifth edition. The game mechanics are usable in your campaign, but at this time they aren’t officially part of the game and aren’t permitted in D&D Adventurers League events. These mechanics will evolve based on player feedback. This is a living document, and as these concepts are refined, this book will also be updated for free—so you will be kept up to date with any changes that are made to it. Beyond that: Eberron is your world as much as it is mine. I hope that this book will provide you with inspiration, but don’t be limited by these ideas or decisions. Think of this as something you can build upon, not a codex of absolute law.

## Current status: Still playtest 11/2019

With the release of the official book *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, Wizards of the Coast have made an official release of Eberron content. While some content in *Wayfinder's* has been updated, the the book remains playtest as the paragraph quoted above remains in the introduction.

If you're looking for fully official and complete Eberron content, your only current choice is *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*.

Comment: @NautArch: Fair enough. I think the main thing to note is that WGTE and this new book are indeed 2 different books/products.

Comment: It might be worth updating this answer now that the *Eberron: Rising from the Last  War* book is out.

Comment: @V2Blast I added another section, but sadly it doesn't seem like the needle has moved much.

Comment: I mean... If RftLW is the final version, and the content in WGtE's been updated to match it, I don't think the lack of removal of the disclaimer means much other than that they didn't bother (or forgot) to remove it.

Comment: @V2Blast That may be true. I haven't gone page-by-page to confirm all content is fully updated to the new release. But making an assumption either way is probably not a great idea. Until they actually update it, i'm going to still call this playtest. Heck, on the DMsGuild page, it still says playtest, but they added a link and more copy directing folks to the new book, too. Multiple instances not updated? No longer a coincidence in my mind.