# What material currently appears in the "Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron" that wasn't reprinted in the "Eberron: Rising from the Last War" book?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, eberron

The [*Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/247882/Wayfinders-Guide-to-Eberron-5e) (WGtE) was originally released on DMsGuild as a PDF (and on D&D Beyond) in July 2018. (See also this Q&A: [What is "Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153856/what-is-wayfinders-guide-to-eberron)) The various parts already included in it (races, dragonmarks, magic items) then went through the Unearthed Arcana public playtest process, as did the artificer class.

Eventually, the final versions of this material were published in [*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/eberron) (E:RftLW) in November 2019. At that point, WGtE was updated to include the final versions (as they appear in E:RftLW) of the content that was already in it; the official artificer class was added to WGtE as well, though with only 1 of the 3 subclasses that appeared in E:RftLW (the Alchemist).

As of the release of *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, it seems like there's almost no reason to buy the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*. Almost every single character option and magic item that exists in WGtE seems to have been reprinted in E:RftLW, and then the latter adds several additional things that are not in WGtE at all: the Artillerist and Battle Smith subclasses for artificer, reprints of bugbears/goblins/hobgoblins, a "new" orc race (though mechanically almost identical to the existing one in *Volo's Guide to Monsters*), a group patrons mechanic, seemingly more in-depth lore, a short sample adventure, several additional magic items, and plenty of new monsters/NPCs.

By the way, this stands in stark contrast to Mike Mearls' claims back when WGtE first came out that any future print product would be complementary, rather than just superseding/replacing WGtE entirely (even if E:RftLW was only a hypothetical at that point):

- > [This book and a theoretical print release will be designed to complement each other, though some material (artificer, races) will be duplicated.](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1021497273757458433)
- > [If we do an Eberron print product, we will design it to complement as much as possible what the PDF presents.](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1021495845223636994)
  > [Some things, like the artificer, races, and basic world info, will be picked up for a print book, but we want fans to be happy owning both.](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1021496102800056321)
- > [yes, but we will build a print product so that the two complement each other.](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1021499541143597057)

However, in responding to [someone's question on /r/dndnext on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/hse2ui/dd_beyond_released_data_on_what_the_most_common/fyzn4gk/?context=3) about which of the 2 books would be a better purchase (to which the answer was obvious), I did begin to wonder what official material appeared exclusively in *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*. The only 2 things I'm aware of are listed in my reply to the linked comment, but I was curious whether there was anything else I'd missed. (I'm intentionally choosing not to state which things I identified in my question, so that answers will contain a complete list of WGtE-exclusive material rather than excluding those two.)

**What material currently appears only in the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* (the latest version, as of November 2019), that wasn't also reprinted in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*?**

I'm mainly interested in a summary/list **mechanical stuff** - e.g. character options, magic items, monsters, etc. - but if there are **significant lore elements** mentioned only in WGtE and not in E:RftLW, it'd be nice to get a brief summary of what lore is exclusive to WGtE as well. (You don't need to provide a full rundown of what that WGtE-exclusive lore is - just list the names of topics/sections that only WGtE has lore about, or point out where in WGtE I can find it.) I might count **maps and other resources** too, if they're exclusive to WGtE.

Basically, I'm curious about any WGtE-only content that a person couldn't get simply by buying E:RftLW.

Comment: Are you also interested in what *changed* between the two? Because they are at odds in some cases (eg. price of travel).

Comment: It isn’t in _Wayfinder’s_ either, but _Rising from the Last War_ did ditch at least two things from the penultimate artificer: the archivist subclass, and the _many-handed bag_ infusion. We have a [Q&A on the class’s history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/163325/4563), which notes those and some other changes.

Comment: @Szega: That'd probably be better as a separate question, if anything (i.e. "What material in E:RftLW contradicts material in the most recent version of WGtE" or something like that). This is mostly just to figure out what material is in WGtE but not in E:RftLW.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I noticed was certain magic items (such as a Band of Loyalty) weren't reprinted, the same goes for the Warforged subraces, which did not get updates or reprints. The Valenar and Aereni (elf) subraces did not get reprinted either, for reasons I am not currently aware at the moment. Hope this was helpful!