# Is Elven High Magic an official source of information, or a 3rd Party Unofficial idea?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, elf

I have been working on making Shadow Monk character who's clan specializes in improving the world's Ki from the shadows (via guarding key players, gathering incriminating evidence, or eliminating direct threats without disrupting the status quo).

In searching for what Elf would best fit in my character build, I came across [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obiVOd6wjFk) by MrRhexx that focused on breaking down the lore, history, magic, life cycle and abilities of an elf, while sourcing official materials that one could find on DndBeyond, but also mentioned things I could not find on the site.

Notably, in the video linked, MrRhexx talked about how Elven High Magic is studied; Spending 60 years learning the flow of nature in order to start seeing "the weave" and how it flows throughout the world, focusing your magic to alter the flow of "the weave" rather than disrupting it as other wizards and mages do. At 9:30, he mentioned how this ability to see the weave allowed you to see magical disruptions caused by illusions and such as if you cast "Detect Magic" but not having to do so.

Seeing this as a beautiful interpretation of how a monk might study and understand Ki and learn to use the flow in combat, I searched DndBeyond for more information on this practice and regrettably only found a few racial feats for each type of Elf, but not the practice itself. However, turning to Google, I found a document called [Deep Magic: Elven High Magic for 5th Edition](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/211148/Deep-Magic-Elven-High-Magic-for-5th-Edition&affiliate_id=877416?src=nerdarchy-ad&affiliate_id=877416) and a video from [Nerdarchy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uis5BRUK9cs) that made a review on it.

Putting everything together, **I was wondering where the source of this information comes from and if it's official D&D Lore or a 3rd Party material.** I am unsure if Kobalt Press is an official source, or if they are more homebrew, though, as I mentioned, MrRhexx listed the following sources, which doesn't include this Kobalt Press entry:

> - 5e Player's Handbook
> - Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes
> - Races of Faerun
> - Sword Coast Adventures Guide
> - Dragon Magazine #354
> - Elves of Evermeet
> - Grand History of the Realms
> - Cormanthy: Empire of Elves

Comment: You're using the term RAW, but the problem is that High Magic doesn't exist as an official class or race feature. Please specify if you're interested in what the actual rules say about it (i.e. nothing unfortunately) or if you're interested in D&D lore on the subject (which is a different question, High Magic certainly "exists" in some D&D lore but lore aren't rules). The entire last paragraph seems to be about fluff about your characters background which is offtopic for this site. Please condense you question down to a single, answerable question

Comment: Hi @Victor B  This is a Kobold specific publication. You can modify your question so it includes the 3rd-party tag. All the Deep Magig series from Kobold are 3rd-party materials. That might in itself might be the answer you were looking for. :)

Comment: Between homebrew and RAW, you seem to ignore third category — 3rd party books, with two subcategories, licensed and unlicensed.

Comment: Ah thank you everyone, I used homebrew but I'm glad to see the proper wording. Will fix it right away.

Comment: A more general note: MrRhexx liberally combines material pulled from editions, novels, and settings that do not fully align. His examples of how to cure petrification versus what's in the 5e Monster Manual is one example of this (since that's the edition you're playing). It's not that his lore remixes are bad, but the reason "they don't tell you" the stuff in his videos is because what he presents is not all canon at any single point in time, even if each piece can be verified individually.

Answer (score 8):

## It is not official

It is not published by Wizards of the Coast, but by Kobold Press and is simply third party content.

There is an existing stack question that tries to maintain a list of all official sourcebooks [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/where-do-i-find-the-official-rules-for-dd-5e).