# All the different mechanics that offer rerolls/replacement results

Tags: dnd-5e, dice

Can we get an exhaustive list of ways to reroll, or change the result of, a die?

I'm currently only concerned with yourself or your allies rolls.

Comment: I think this question is probably bounded enough for a list question once you answer medix2's clarification request. But it also feels like a 'can someone do the research for me".

Comment: Just rerolls. And either for yourself or Allies. @NautArch fair enough, I suppose there's no reason I can't do that

Comment: @jonnybolton16 If you include a list of ones you already know about to the main question and ask if there are any others, there would be enough effort put in that I don't think anyone would have any issues.

Comment: @Axoren It's better to keep the question as just a question rather than have partial answers in it.

Comment: I think official, yes. I'm not sure what UA actually is?

Comment: [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84837) explains which rules are official and mentions Unearthed Arcana: "Unearthed Arcana are articles published by Wizards of the Coast featuring new rules or options. However, they are explicitly experimental and not official."

Comment: TBH the "can we get" expression somehow irks me. Maybe because of the aforementioned "do the research for me" vibe... I didn't downvote or VTC for it, but I would advise you to rephrase it.

Comment: how would you like me to rephrase it?

Comment: I assume you are *not* interested in features which add modifiers to various rolls such as the Bard's Cutting Words? What about features which guarantee a failure/miss or success/hit? What about features that turn a failure/miss into a success/hit (or the opposite)?

Answer (score 2):

### Racial Traits

- Lucky (Halfling)

  > When you roll a 1 on the d20 for an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll.

### Class Features

#### Barbarian

- Indomitable Might

  > [...]  if your total for a Strength check is less than your Strength score, you can use that score in place of the total.
- Zealot Barbarian's Fanatatical Focus

  Allows you to reroll failed saving throws

#### Bard

- Eloquence Bard's Silver Tongue

  Allows you to replace the d20 roll on specific ability checks you make with a 10

#### Druid

- Stars Druid's Dragon Starry Form

Allows you to replace the d20 roll on specific ability checks you make with a 10

#### Fighter

- Indomitable

  > [...] you can reroll a saving throw that you fail. If you do so, you must use the new roll [...]
- Arcane Archer's Curving Shot

  Allows you to reroll missed attack rolls

#### Monk

- Martial Arts

  > [...] You can roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon. [...]
- Diamond Soul

  > [...] whenever you make a saving throw and fail, you can spend 1 ki point to reroll it and take the second result.
- Kensei Monk's Unerring Accuracy

  Allows you to reroll missed attack rolls

#### Paladin

- Glory Paladin's Living Legend

  Allows you to reroll failed saving throws

#### Rogue

- Reliable Talent

  > [...] Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.
- Stroke of Luck

  > [...] if you fail an ability check, you can treat the d20 roll as a 20 [...]
- Inquisitive Rogue's Ear for Deceit

  Allows you to replace the d20 roll on specific ability checks you make with an 8
- Swashbuckler Rogue's Master Duelist

  Allows you to reroll a missed attack roll with advantage

#### Sorcerer

- Empowered Spell Metamagic

  > [...] you can spend 1 sorcery point to reroll a number of the damage dice up to your Charisma modifier [...]
- Divine Soul Sorcerer's Empowered Healing

  Allows you to reroll dice rolled for healing spells

#### Wizard

- Chronurgy Wizard's Chronal Shift

  Allows you to force a reroll of an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw
- Divination Wizard's Portent

  Allows you to replace an attack roll, saving throw, or ability check.

#### Fighting Styles

- Great Weapon Fighting (Fighter and Paladin)

  > When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll, even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2. [...]

### Feats

- Durable

  Increases the minimum hit points restored when spending Hit Dice
- Savage Attacker

  Allows you to reroll melee damage rolls
- Elemental Adept (Spellcaster)

  Allows you to treat 1's as 2's on certain spell damage rolls
- Bountiful Luck (Halfling)

  Allows allies to reroll 1's on ability checks, attack rolls, and saving throws
- Second Change (Halfling)

  Allows you to force an attack that hits you to be rerolled
- Elven Accuracy (Elf or Half-Elf)

  Allows you to reroll certain attack rolls if you have advantage
- Flames of Phlegethos (Tiefling)

  Allows you to reroll 1's on dice when rolling fire damage for spells

### Spells

- *wish*

  > [...] You undo a single recent event by forcing a reroll of any roll made within the last round (including your last turn). [...]
- *glibness*

  > [...] when you make a Charisma check, you can replace the number you roll with a 15. [...]

### Magic Items

- Any magic item that can cast *wish*
- Ring of Evasion

  > [...] When you fail a Dexterity saving throw while wearing it, you can use your reaction to expend 1 of its charges to succeed on that saving throw instead.
- Luck Blade

  > [...] If the sword is on your person, you can call on its luck (no action required) to reroll one attack roll, ability check, or saving throw you dislike. [...]
- Dragon Masks

  Allow you to succeed on failed saving throws
- Clockwork Amulet

  Allows you to forgo an attack roll and treat the d20 as having rolled a 10

Comment: happy to make a community wiki. I'd imagine entirely exhaustive research would be difficult, easy to miss one somewhere

Comment: also changed the question to reflect this

Comment: I've also seen that Elemental Adept allows you to _change_ the result of a die, rather than _reroll_. So I'd like to include this stuff.

Comment: To stay within fair-use, you may not want to quote every single one of these features directly (certainly the ones in the SRD or Basic Rules can be quoted), though I'm no expert on the various copyright laws

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks, will paraphrase (I suppose someone wanting the full wording could look it up themselves)

Answer (score -1):

An honorable mention would be "Law of Averages" while on the plane Mechanus, which treats all damage rolls as automatically ½ maximum (2d6+5 is always 11, because each d6 is automatically treated as a 3).

Comment: You seem to be quoting the related "Law of Not Quite Averages". The (optional) rule for mechanus states *average* damage, not half-maximum. So 2d6+5 is always 12. (Note that the example in the DMG works out as half maximum because it was 1d10+5 which averages 10.5, rounded down to 10 - anything with more than one die won't work out that way)